# Better Stack than the one that extends Vector

Tags: java, collections

I just noticed that `Stack` extends `Vector` in Java, ref: [here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java).
`Vector` is slower than `ArrayList` so is there a better Stack I can use?

Thanks.

Comment: You can have a look at Deque/ArrayDeque.

Comment: While I dislike the fact that `Stack` extends `Vector`, do you have any reason to believe the speed different is significant in your case?

Comment: By slower, it means 10-100 nano-seconds per method call.  Is that critical to you?

Comment: Btw, the (old crappy) Vector is slower also because it is thread-safe, while ArrayList is not (unless you are using Collection.synchronizedList to generate it), and *that* may be critical for you...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

java.util.ArrayDeque has all stack methods (pop, push, peek) and it is fast. API *This class is likely to be faster than Stack when used as a stack, and faster than LinkedList when used as a queue.*

Answer (score 2):

You can use Apache's ArrayStack that is based on ArrayList instead of Vector:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections/ArrayStack.html

Answer (score 0):

I find that LinkedList does a good job when you only need to access the front (and back) of a data structure. It adds with complexity O(1) and gets from the front also with O(1). It also never has to worry about resizing the backing array.